# Pointer movement causes apps to slide out of VDU view

Tags: mouse, external-display

I use a laptop with Windows 10 and MS Office applications, and extend the display area to two additional VDUs (VDU 2, VDU 3).  If I display an app (e.g. Excel, Adobe Reader) on VDU 2 in near-full-screen view, and move my mouse pointer quickly toward the lower portion of the display area, the app will slide upwards (automatically) so that the upper section of the displayed app (including the header/menu ribbon area) will be out of view.  I have to 'bounce' the mouse pointer against the upper boundary of that VDU display area to get the app to creep back down into full, original view.  I don't want this 'pointer-led sliding out of view' to carry on.
What's going on, here?
How do I prevent it in Settings?

[Visualisation and description of the 'app/document sliding up' problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlmpY.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See 'visualisation and description' via the hyperlink (png image), which hopefully clarifies.